# Align unnumbered equations when converting latex to html

Tags: equations, align, tex4ht, tex4ebook

I am trying to create an ebook from a tex file using the `tex4ebook` command. I have numbered and unnumbered equations using `align`.  I am able to align equations using `pic-align` in the `.cfg` file, but this only works for numbered equations, not for unnumbered equations:

[image: Example showing that the alignment of unnumbered equations looks different from that of numbered equations]

I believe the reason is that the equation is converted to an image and is then flushed to the right (because equation numbers should appear at the right). Without the equation number, the flush-right does not look right.

Is there a way to align unnumbered equations better?

MWE:

I am using this command:

`tex4ebook alignequations.tex -c my.cfg`

My `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,pic-align}
\ConfigureEnv{equation}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="equation">}\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\Css{div.align,div.equation{text-align:right;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Numbered equation
\begin{align}
 y =\beta_0 + \beta_1 x +\epsilon 
\end{align}
Unnumbered equation:
\begin{align*}
 y =\beta_0 + \beta_1 x +\epsilon
\end{align*}
Mixed: 
\begin{align}
 y =\beta_0 + \beta_1 x +\epsilon \nonumber \\
 y =\beta_0 + \beta_1 x +\epsilon 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

In response to a comment by @Mico I also tried using `equation` instead of `align`.  Unnumbered equations flush left instead of right, but the problem is the same. The updated screenshot is here:

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you using `align` and `align*` environments for the first two equations? Why not `equation` and `equation*`?

Comment: Quite a few times I started out with one equation, and then I added another. So I had to switch from ```begin{equation}``` to ```begin{align}``` . At some point I started using ```align``` to begin with.    I could switch to ```equation``` if there is only one; but that does not solve the problem either (I tried).

Comment: The `\Picture*` command makes a minimal box around it's content, so if equation doesn't contain number, it will be shorter. I've tried to redefine `align*` to produce some extra space on the right, but with no success. I think that it looks much better when you use `text-align: center` in the CSS code.